# PDO query results not properly going into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am building a web forum for practice using new techniques that I honestly haven't used before.  Specifically, I'm using PDO instead of mysqli and it's been pretty peach until this most recent hang-up.

The big thing I'm trying to do right now is select all of the rows from my `posts` table, put it into an associative array, and then loop through each row to output the data so people can pick which thread they want to open up.

Right now what is currently happening is I'm only getting one row in my array.  I know it's not my SQL because when I run it outside of the web browser it works as intended, so I think it's something do with either how i'm trying to iterate through the results or how I'm storing the information in my return variable.  Here's my code...

```
function get_posts($board){
    include("db_connect.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts
                WHERE board = ?
                ORDER BY stickied DESC, date DESC";
    try{
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindValue(1, $board, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();
        $results = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
    }
    return $results;
}
```

And the code for running through it on my web-page...

```
$posts[] = get_posts(1);

// output all of the posts
print_r($posts);
```

The data that it is giving me is...

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
      [user_id] => 1 
      [date] => 2017-02-28 16:58:54 
      [post_id] => 1 
      [board] => 1 
      [stickied] => 1 
      [post_text] => Please Ignore 
      [post_title] => Test Post Please Ignore 
    ) 
)
```

There are currently 3 posts (rows) in this table.  I'm aware what I'm missing is probably fundamental in how PDO works, but I just can not figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are all 3 post in your table have `board=1`? it seems only one have `board=1`. Check and confirm

Comment: I don't see an issue here. As @Anant mentioned, you might want to check your `board` id.

Comment: You don't miss anything and the results are going into array properly. Your code returns exact rows that are matched by where condition

Comment: On a side note, remember [you're not the only user of  site](https://phpdelusions.net/programming#reporting_errors). Do not catch errors to report them

Comment: You guys were totally right, @Anant and subwaymatch.  I was passing the wrong board number into the function - which is probably the first thing I should have checked.  It was a careless mistake, thanks for your patience and being awesome folks.

Answer (score 1):

As @anant and @subwaymatch pointed out, the `board` id was = 1 in this thing.  The problem with that is that the board I was *trying* to retrieve information for was board #2.

Thanks everyone for your help.